# Difference between fees and expences

Tags: word-usage

Could you please explain to me the difference between the words fees and expences?

There was a sentence: She also pays most of her  __________.

And I had a number of answer choices:
costs / fees / expenses / payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at each of these words, on the assumption that you are having trouble understanding the dictionary. I will focus on the meanings of each that are closest to the others - the area of overlap, so to speak.

- **Costs**: these are generally things that need paying necessarily. *Cost* is also a verb, meaning to incur costs or to value.
- **Payment**: a payment is when money changes hands, generally in exchange for goods or services. It is the actual handing over of the money (or cheque, or use of a payment card, etc.)
- **Fees**: what someone charges for something. You can have an *entry fee* for a museum or theme park, or be paid a fee for some speaking or writing work. A lawyer charges their clients fees. "*Her fees*" might refer to the fees that are due to her, or the fees she needs to pay.
- **Expenses**: the cost of doing something. A person might talk about their own expenses to mean their cost of living - housing, food, utilities etc. They might also use it to mean the expenses they incurred while doing work for someone - in many voluntary positions, you can be *paid expenses*, meaning that the charity (or whatever) repays you any money you spend in the course of doing work for them. *An expense* is any case of needing to spend money for something.

Comment: Thanks a lot! An in this particular sentence, what should we use? Is "expences" the right answer here?

Comment: Costs and expenses could both work, depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

"Expense" is any money you spend for something, whether you pay for buying some food, objects, contracting some services etc.

"Fee" is the mandatory money you have to pay for something, usually a service:

- for visiting a museum;
- for having some official document released (e.g. passport, some certificate...);
- for education

"Fee" is sometimes (always?) similar with "tax".